# Angular: $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, route-provider, ng-view

I am having issues with setting up my routing. I am getting the following error in my console. My folder 'partials' is named correctly and my files are named correctly. Any help?

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.12/$injector/modulerr?p0=demoApp&p1=Error%3…s%2Fthomasjanszen%2Fcodinghouse%2FAngular%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
  <div ng-view=""></div>  
  </div>
  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['']);

    demoApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/view1', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/view1.html',
        controller: 'SimpleController'
      }).
      when('/view2', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/view2.html',
        controller: 'SimpleController'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/view1'
      });
  }]);

    // demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function($scope){
    //   $scope.customers=[
    //     {name: 'name1', city: 'Cincinnati'},
    //      {name: 'name2', city: 'NYC'}, 
    //      {name: 'name3', city: 'Denver'}, 
    //      {name: 'name4', city: 'Chicago'}
    //   ];
    //   $scope.addCustomer = function(){
    //     $scope.customers.push(
    //         {
    //           name: $scope.newCustomer.name,
    //           city: $scope.newCustomer.city
    //         });
    //   };
    // });
  </script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you click on error link and paste error trace.

Comment: It's probably the empty string in the module definition....change [''] to [].

Comment: Try changing the [''] for [] in "demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['']);"

Answer (score 3):

From angular 1.2 onwards, if you want angular routing you need to

- Include the JS file : `<script src="angular-route.js"></script>`
  You can obtain `angular-route.js` for your version of angular (1.3.12) here: https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.12/
- provide ngRoute as a dependency, i.e.

change this:

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['']);
```

to this

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

For details please refer to the [AngularJS Developers Doc - migration guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#ngroute-has-been-moved-into-its-own-module)

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject 'ng-route' as a dependency in your module

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ng-route']);
```

Comment: Ah @Michael beat me to it!, you may need to add a script include to angular-route.js too, not sure if that's already in min.js file?